# how to enable package level logging in log4j

Tags: logging, log4j, package

Can any one tell me, what is package level logging in log4j ?
And how to enable this, today my interview question am unable to answer this :-(

Even i didn't find good solution in Google.

thank you so much.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Package level logging is the standard logging of log4j. With log4j configuration, you'd specify the package and the associated level.

In the [intro example](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html), there is package level logging for "com.foo".

```
# Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package com.foo.
log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
```

Comment: You mean, with package level logging we can specify the particular level for selected packages right ? 

For example this is my .properties file
-------------------------------------------

log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG,abc
log4j.appender.abc = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.abc.file = my.txt
log4j.appender.abc.layout = org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout

how can i specify ?

Comment: in your example you have defined appender name "abc" and associated that with the root logger. If you'd want to associate that with a "com.foo" package, you'd need to have something like
log4j.logger.com.foo=DEBUG, abc

Comment: @eis How about asking to log for all my source classes; i.e. all those within the "java" sources folder? What is the name of the very top level package in the java project? I need this because I am using a maven based project and the log file is putting logs from all the dependencies inside the log file.

Comment: @bikashg try `root` logger for that. If you have issues, please open another question for it.