# How to enable log4j for this package

Tags: java, log4j, portal-java

I'm trying to setup log4j `DEBUG` level for `com.github.flowersinthesand`

My log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.github.flowersinthesand=DEBUG,stdout
```

According to [how to enable package level logging in log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648681/how-to-enable-package-level-logging-in-log4j) I'm doing this correctly unless my package name is incorrect.  I got the package name from maven, assuming it would cover all libraries.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.flowersinthesand</groupId>
        <artifactId>portal-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.flowersinthesand</groupId>
        <artifactId>portal-spring</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

How come this package isn't being logged at all?

**update**

In response to Lucas' confirmation that my log4j config is correct.

Main.java

```
package com.production;

public class Main {

    protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        logger.info("Starting server...");
        final HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer(".", 80);

        WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("Socket", "/");

        //enable annotation configuration
        ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextClass", "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
        ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "com");

        //allow spring to do all of it's stuff
        ctx.addListener("org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener");

        //enable web socket support
        final WebSocketAddOn addon = new WebSocketAddOn();
        for (NetworkListener listener : server.getListeners()) {
            listener.registerAddOn(addon);

            //if false, local files (html, etc.) can be modified without restarting the server
            listener.getFileCache().setEnabled(false);
        }

        //add jersey servlet support
        ServletRegistration jerseyServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("JerseyServlet", new SpringServlet());
        jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.resource");
        jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters", "com.resource.ResponseCorsFilter");
        jerseyServletRegistration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
        jerseyServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        jerseyServletRegistration.addMapping("/api/*");

        //deploy
        logger.info("Deploying server...");
        ctx.deploy(server);

        server.start();

        //start the production process
        Production.init();

        System.in.read();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

Config.java

```
package com;

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
            "com"
    })
    @PropertySource(value= {
            "classpath:/application.properties",
            "classpath:/environment-${MY_ENVIRONMENT}.properties"
    })
    @EnableJpaRepositories("com.repository")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class Config {
        @Value("${db.url}")
        String PROPERTY_DATABASE_URL;
        @Value("${db.user}")
        String PROPERTY_DATABASE_USER;
        @Value("${db.password}")
        String PROPERTY_DATABASE_PASSWORD;

        @Value("${persistenceUnit.default}")
        String PROPERTY_DEFAULT_PERSISTENCE_UNIT;

        @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
        String PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_DIALECT;
        @Value("${hibernate.format_sql}")
        String PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL;
        @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
        String PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;
        @Value("${entitymanager.packages.to.scan}")
        String PROPERTY_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

        @Autowired
        private BeanFactory beanFactory;

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();

            dataSource.setUrl(PROPERTY_DATABASE_URL);
            dataSource.setUser(PROPERTY_DATABASE_USER);
            dataSource.setPassword(PROPERTY_DATABASE_PASSWORD);

            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

            return transactionManager;
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

            entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName(PROPERTY_DEFAULT_PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(PROPERTY_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);

            Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL);
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);

            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

            return entityManagerFactoryBean;
        }

        @Bean
        public ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider() {
            return new ApplicationContextProvider();
        }

        /**
         * This bean is required for @Value injection from .properties files
         */
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer () {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }

        @Bean
        public App app() {
            return new App(new Options().url("/socket/workstation/approval").packageOf(ApprovalSocketHandler.class), new SpringModule(beanFactory));
        }
    }
```

Comment: maven groupId is not _necessarily_ the same as java package name.  frequently they are, but it is not a requirement.  (I just checked the source code, and it is the correct package, but the prior statement still stands)

Comment: do you get any log messages?  or is it just flowersinthesand debug messages that are missing?

Comment: @Lucas - When `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,stdout` it debugs hibernate, but that's it.  I don't see any other packages show up there.  I'm using `Spring` and `Grizzly` as well.

Comment: Well, I can tell you that your log4j.properties file is correct for what you are asking.  That means something else is going on.  Which servlet container are you using?  Where did you place your log4j.properties?  What does your applicationContext.xml look like (is it initializing log4j or is it allowing the container to initialize log4j)?

Comment: @Lucas - I appreciate the confirmation.  I've grown quite frustrated with `log4j`.  I'm using `Grizzly` and don't have an `applicationContext.xml`.  I'll update my original post with my config and `Main.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `log4j.logger` I needed `log4j.category`

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c:%L - %m%n

log4j.category.com.github.flowersinthesand=TRACE
log4j.category.org.atmosphere=TRACE
```

Answer (score 0):

Grizzly uses JUL logging: [can not get grizzly logging to work, nothing written to my log4j log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12370984/516433).  You will need to initialize your own log4j instance to write to stdout in order to get log4j to add to the Grizzly log.  I use:

```
  <bean id="log4jConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
    <property name="arguments">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:log4j.properties</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

But since you are using code config for spring rather than xml config, you will probably need to look at the details of [Log4jConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Log4jConfigurer.html)

Comment: This looked promising: https://gist.github.com/yanaga/1886540 But it didn't solve any issues :-\

Comment: The thing is, it is reading my `log4j.properties`.  I can toggle the `log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout` and see the changes in the log.  I can `DEBUG`, but it doesn't affect other classes.

Comment: if the other classes log with slf4j or jul instead of commons-logging or log4j directly, then you will need the appropriate adapter library (slf4j-log4j12 and jcl-over-slf4j, or jul-to-slf4j off the top of my head...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was an issue with the logging packages being included in my project.  The solutions outlined in [Why does this only log for hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223764/why-does-this-only-log-for-hibernate/16224823) resolved this issue