# Why does this only log for hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, log4j, grizzly

Within my `log4j.properties`, `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout` only shows debug data for hibernate.  Can anyone explain this?  I'm trying to debug other packages but none of them will work.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: can you post your full log4j config?

Comment: try add something like `log4j.category.YOUR_PACKAGE=DEBUG`

Comment: maybe also add code snippet, how do you write log..

Comment: @Jaiwo99 - I'm trying to debug a class off of GitHub, here's the base class: https://github.com/flowersinthesand/portal-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/github/flowersinthesand/portal/App.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that you do `NOT` have log4j in your pom, you need these 3 dependencies to log with log4j and slf4j:

```
slf4j-api-x.x.x.jar
slf4j-log4j12-x.x.x.jar
log4j-x.x.x.jar
```

log4j and slf4j-log4j12 should have the same version.

Please also note the commet from @Stefan Lindenberg

Comment: Thats right, but dont forget jcl-over-slf4j.jar to redirect commons-logging (i.e. Spring,...) to log4j and exclude commons-logging.jar from spring-core.jar.